# Complete list of layers available in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Recently Wildfly project introduced a galleon app, which allows creation of smaller app servers. But I couldn't find a comprehensive list of available layers.

Doc suggests:

```
galleon.sh install wildfly:current --dir=my-wildfly-server --layers=cdi,jaxrs
```

operation finished fine, but resulting Wildfly doesn't really start my SOAP war.

```
13:33:25,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/wf/soap/standalone/data/content/01/a5f89d915b85b778b64fcf071d45f0efa84f0b/content
13:33:25,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "soap01.war" (runtime-name: "soap01.war")
13:33:26,032 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/soap01' for server 'default-server'
13:33:26,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "soap01.war" (runtime-name : "soap01.war")
```

This war works fine with full Wildfly. WSDL is available, service working.

There is no layer named jaxws, so I guess jaxrs is fine.

SOAP is just an example, it would be great to see full list of layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we don't have a layer for webservices. That is something that we could add. The full list of layers can be found there: http://docs.wildfly.org/16/Admin_Guide.html#Galleon_Provisioning

I just created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-11795 to track this requirement.

Updated: Starting WildFly 21 we have a layer for webservices. The list of Galleon layers for WildFly 26 is there: https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Bootable_Guide.html#wildfly_layers
JF

Comment: Thank you! Nice of you.

Comment: @jean-francois-denise, it would be super awesome if it would be possible to build a full WildFly server with Galeon. Our team wants to run a lean full profile server in Docker without the jsf, jsr77, sar, iio etc legacy or not needed modules. Fingers crossed for your success to make it possible in the future!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that accepted answer is not correct for later versions. However, at least the Wildfly 25 layers are available here: https://docs.wildfly.org/25/Bootable_Guide.html

I expect you'll find some of the earlier versions on similar locations.

Comment: Accepted answer says, that there is no SOAP layer, not list of layers. As far as I see, there is still no such layer (WFLY-11795 is open). (Actually, I do not care now -switched to sp*ng)

Comment: OP's question as written on his last line was: "it would be great to see full list of layers". That was the same answer I came here looking for; alas it  was outdated. (Good luck with Spång ;-) )